# Regex not working in LIKE condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently using Oracle SQL developer and am trying to write a query that will allow me to search for all fields that resemble a certain value but always differ from it.

```
SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE last_name LIKE 'Do[^e]%';
```

So the result that I'm after would be: Give me all last names that start with 'Do' but are not 'Doe'.

I got the square brackets method from a general SQL basics book so I assume any SQL database should be able to run it.

This is my first post and I'd be happy to clarify if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501

Comment: if you want to use regexp, you shoul have a look at `REGEXP_LIKE` instead of `like`

Comment: I tried to but then I got the following error message: 00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle's [`LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) no regular expressions can be used. But you can use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Name, '^Do[^e]');
```

The `^` at the beginning of the pattern anchors it to the beginning of the compared string. In other words the string must start with the pattern to match. And there is no wildcard needed at the end, as there is no anchor for the end of the string (which would be `$`). And you seem to already know the meaning of `[^e]`.

Comment: The problem is that my instance of Oracle doesn't seem to recognize it. when I replace LIKE with REGEXP_LIKE I get the following error: 00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator". Perhaps I need to change something in my query before REGEXP_LIKE?

Comment: That's because the initial version was wrong; now it is fixed.

Comment: @BK-GG - that's because it isn't quite as simple as the answer originally showed; see the edited version, or the documentation link.

Comment: @BK-GG: Sorry I confused that. See the edits and comments of the others. Thanks to them BTW.

Comment: Yes the edited answer did the trick! The REGEXP_LIKE works slightly different in terms of how the query needs to be formulated but I finally got it working. Thanks a lot to sticky and all the others who helped out.